# Curve fitting in Python subject to the constraint of having positive derivative

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to fit a quadratic polynomial to data, subject to the constraint that the polynomial should have positive derivative for `x>0`.

Without the constraint, the following works:

```
def poly(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b*x + c*x**2

popt, pcov = curve_fit(poly, x, y)
```

where `x,y` contain the data to be fit to.

How do I add in the constraint that `b+cx` should be positive when `x>0`?

Comment: That's impossible. Parabolas cannot have a positive derivative everywhere.

Comment: Maybe you mean the derivative "should be positive in all the given points"? Obviously `b + cx` will always be negative for some values of `x`.

Comment: Ah yes. I mean `b+cx` should be positive for `x>0`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the derivative of `a + b*x + c*x**2` is `b + 2*c*x`, not `b + c*x`.

Second, we need to replace "positive" by "nonnegative", because optimization by its nature requires a closed region of allowable parameters.

The expression `b + 2*c*x` is nonnegative for `x>0` if and only if `b>=0` and `c>=0`. Hence, the problem is solved by providing suitable lower bounds on b and c to `curve_fit`, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_data = [2, 1, 2, 5, 9]
def poly(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b*x + c*x**2
result = curve_fit(poly, x_data, y_data, bounds=((-np.inf, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)))
print(result[0])
```

The result `[2.70588235e-01 1.92685605e-15 3.20855615e-01]` shows that b is effectively zero (it's being pushed against the constraint), so the fit is better expressed as `y = 0.271 + 0.321 * x**2`.